# About SNMP info to MySQL used Fluentd

Tags: mysql, snmp, fluentd

I used "fluent-plugin-snmp" and "fluent-plugin-mysql" want to get snmp info and save in MySQL.

but I can't save SNMP info to MySQL

my config code is

```
<source>
  type snmp
  tag snmpser1
  nodes name, value
  host localhost
  community public
  mib sysDescr.0, sysName.0
  method_type get
  polling_time 10
  polling_type async_run
</source>

<match snmpser*>
  @type mysql_bulk
  host localhost
  database test01
  username root
  password password
  column_names name,value
  key_names data01,data02
  table new_table
  flush_interval 10s
</match>
```

but it can't save in mysql.

error info is

```
2017-09-08 14:05:53 -0700 [info]: #0 bulk insert values size (table: new_table) => 2
2017-09-08 14:05:53 -0700 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=1 next_retry_seconds=2017-09-08 14:05:53 -0700 chunk="558b3f08bf79121a7b4d669b30703220" error_class=Mysql2::Error error="Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'"
  2017-09-08 14:05:53 -0700 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2017-09-08 14:05:55 -0700 [info]: #0 bulk insert values size (table: new_table) => 2
2017-09-08 14:05:55 -0700 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=2 next_retry_seconds=2017-09-08 14:05:55 -0700 chunk="558b3f08bf79121a7b4d669b30703220" error_class=Mysql2::Error error="Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'"
```

so...what should I do?

Comment: There's no code here, just some config and some errors. Is this a programming problem?

Comment: Input "fluent-plugin-snmp" config  output "stdout"  running is success, but output used "fluent-plugin-mysql" is error.
I'm sure snmp and mysql settings is correct, or what information should I provide?